# How to get the ID to register a test device for unity ads

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityads

[image]

How and where can I see this number needed to register a test device in unity ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends wheter its what phone you are using if its an Android based phone for example you can find that number behind the battery usually or with simple commands on the phone itself,

e.g. (Android) https://www.verizonwireless.com/b2c/findDeviceId/helpOverlay.jsp?pageName=androidPhone

(Iphone) https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT204073

that number just tells unity that any ads running on that device are test ads and treat them so.

Comment: I wasn't able to locate the ID in the About area of m iPhone, so I used this app to retrieve the key: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-identifiers/id564618183?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

For Android device.
Open google settings from device.
Navigate to services->Ads.
Advertising id for your android device will there.